# Windows Azure with Apache + Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, azure

First of all i will expose my case. I'm working with a virtual machine Windows Azure, Windows Srver 2012. I installed Apache + 2 Tomcats with mod jk to create a load balancer server. I think the problem is with Azure or Windows Server, I reinstalled like a 10 times and doesn't work. 
My problem is, when I acces to my localhost:(Apache port) I returned 502 or 503 http error.
Separately, Tomcats work but when I acces by apache I can't.

I tried putting off the Firewall, adding new rules in Inbound Rules, but nothing.

http://gyazo.com/e6a4ab96e342ac77878f09bb977987b8
http://gyazo.com/47cfc9b05f53c7bc16ba898674f04160

Comment: It seems you have an issue with your Apache installation/configuration.  Can you describe the Apache config and the layout of your system (What is install on each machines)

Answer (score 0):

I have each servers in the same machine with localhost. I installed the same configuration in other Windows Server 2008 and do the same.
But in my laptop i installed the same and works fine. Only in Windows Servers don't work.
I did these steps:

**1.** Install Apache + 2 Tomcats with diferents, http, shutdown and AJP ports.

**2.** Put mod_jk into APACHE_HOME/modules

**3.** Put file workers.properties into APACHE_HOME/conf as this:

```
 workers.tomcat_home=C:\Servers2\t3
 workers.java_home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51   
 worker.list=balancer     
 #Tomcat 1  
 worker.worker1.port=9202  
 worker.worker1.host=localhost  
 worker.worker1.type=ajp13   
 worker.worker1.lbfactor=1    
 #Tomcat 2  
 worker.worker2.port=9205  
 worker.worker2.host=localhost  
 worker.worker2.type=ajp13   
 worker.worker2.lbfactor=1  

 worker.balancer.type=lb  
 worker.balancer.balance_workers=worker1,worker2  
 worker.balancer.method=B    
 worker.balancer.sticky_session=true
```

**4.** Add in APACHE_HOME/conf/http this:

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

JkWorkersFile C:\Servers2\apache\conf\workers.properties

JkMount /* balancer
```

**5.** Add in each TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server

```
Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="worker2"
```

And with this should works, I don't know with my laptop don't have problems and when I installed this in Windows Server don't work.
I tried taking off firewall, adding Inbound and Outbound New Rules but nothing.

Exactly, I can acces to my Tomcats ports, but when I access to Apache port give me 502 and 503 error, and in logs have this.

```
 [Thu Feb 13 17:38:04.856 2014] [3868:2996] [info]
 ajp_connection_tcp_get_message::jk_ajp_common.c (1259): (worker2)
 can't receive the response header message from tomcat, tomcat
 (127.0.0.1:9205) has forced a connection close for socket 308 [Thu Feb
 13 17:38:04.856 2014] [3868:2996] [error]
 ajp_get_reply::jk_ajp_common.c (2126): (worker2) Tomcat is down or
 refused connection. No response has been sent to the client (yet) [Thu
 Feb 13 17:38:04.856 2014] [3868:2996] [info]
 ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2623): (worker2) sending request to
 tomcat failed (recoverable),  (attempt=2) [Thu Feb 13 17:38:04.856
 2014] [3868:2996] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2643):
 (worker2) connecting to tomcat failed. [Thu Feb 13 17:38:04.856 2014]
 [3868:2996] [info] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1478): service failed,
 worker worker2 is in error state [Thu Feb 13 17:38:04.856 2014]
 [3868:2996] [info] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1558): All tomcat
 instances are busy or in error state [Thu Feb 13 17:38:04.856 2014]
 [3868:2996] [error] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1563): All tomcat
 instances failed, no more workers left [Thu Feb 13 17:38:04.856 2014]
 [3868:2996] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2788): Service error=0 for
 worker=balancer
```